# how to install the Nautilus Coverflow?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I have read about the app called nautilus coverflow and I like it so much.

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1719862

I am recently running ubuntu 12.04 and I want to install it. Is it even possible?

[image]